# Как получить данные по внешнему ключу и записать их в TreeView? C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Есть три таблицы:

Таблица "Types"

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Types] (
[TypeID]   INT  NOT NULL,
[NameType] TEXT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Types] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TypeID] ASC));
```

Таблица "Status"

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Status] (
[StatusID]   INT  NOT NULL,
[NameStatus] TEXT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Status] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([StatusID] ASC));
```

Таблица "Objects"

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Objects] (
[ObjectID]   INT  NOT NULL,
[NameObject] TEXT NOT NULL,
[TypeID]     INT  NOT NULL,
[StatusID]   INT  NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Objects] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ObjectID] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Objects_Types] FOREIGN KEY ([TypeID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Types] ([TypeID]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Objects_Status] FOREIGN KEY ([StatusID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Status] ([StatusID]));
```

Ранее писал такой запрос, но он не работает:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("
        SELECT TypeID, StatusID FROM [Objects] 
          WHERE TypeID = TypeID 
          FROM [Types] StatusID = StatusID 
          FROM [Status]"
, connect);
```

Как получить NameType и NameStatus по внешнему ключу и записать их в TreeView? Помогите пожалуйста.
Результат примерно такой: 
Redline > 
1)Rifle 
2)Field-Tested
Asiimov >
1)Rifle
2)Battle-Scared
и т.д.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ваш запрос выглядит странно, напишите нормальный запрос

Comment: дайте пример данных из каждой из таблиц и то, что вы хотите получить в результате запроса

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis Добавил изображения к вопросу

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это должно помочь получить нужные Вам данные

```
Select p.NameObject, s.NameStatus, t.NameType
from Objects o
join Types t on o.typeid=t.id
join Status s on o.statusid=s.id
```

Comment: Спасибо большое